# Different behavior for object and in explorer 9 and all other browsers and versions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

I'm trying to user a DOM element that i am saving into a JS var:

```
lastCheckBoxChecked = this;
```

"this" represents a input/checkbox DOM element.

Now, trying to get if the checkbox is checked from the element with:

```
if(lastCheckBoxChecked.getAttribute('checked') == true)
```

doesn't work.
When I checked what does `lastCheckBoxChecked` holds, I found out that in **IE9** it holds `Object` and when writing

```
alert(lastCheckBoxChecked.getAttribute('checked'))
```

I am getting the correct value but in **firefox** and **chrome** it holds
`object HTMLInputElement` and there is no functionality (getting undefined).

I don't know if this is the reason I am not getting anything, but this is my direction.

Does any one know any thing about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, just use this:

```
if(lastCheckBoxChecked.checked)
    ...
```

Not:

```
if(lastCheckBoxChecked.getAttribute('checked') == true)
```

`getAttribute` checks for the initial state of the checkbox, or if it was changed with `getAttribute` only. User operations have no effect on it.

Answer (score 3):

An *attribute* represents the value it had initially, and which does not change by user interactions. To get the current value, use its *property*:

```
lastCheckBoxChecked.checked
```